# UIViewControllerでUITableViewのdelegateを呼び出すのが上手くいきません。

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

xcode6
master-detail-appのテンプレート,coredata使用で始めました。

TableViewControllerで追加ボタンを押すと、右下のViewControllerに移動して
そのViewControllerの保存ボタンを押すと
デリゲートによって,insertNewObjectメソッドが呼ばれてTableViewセルを追加。
というふうにしたいのですが（イメージはアラームアプリの新規登録です)
うまくいきません。
[image: StoryBoardの全体像です。左半分は今回関係ありません。]
[image: ズームアップ画像]
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)insertNewObject:(id)sender;

@end


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButtom;
@property(nonatomic,weak)id <myProtocol>  delegate4486;

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

　- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
　}

　- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
　}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little    preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

　- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {

    if([_delegate4486 respondsToSelector:@selector(insertNewObject:)]){
        [_delegate4486 insertNewObject:_saveButtom];

    　　}
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }

　- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
　}

　@end
```

上でif([_delegate4486 responds...])の中身をBreak Pointで設定しても
ビルドが通ってしまいます。
MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController: UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,myProtocol>

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

 @end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

　@interface MasterViewController ()

　@end

　@implementation MasterViewController

　- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
　}

　- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    ViewController* viewC=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    viewC.delegate4486 =self;
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
　}

　- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
　}

　- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
   　 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController    managedObjectContext];
    　NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest]  entity];
   　 NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.   You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
//以下省略
```

Break Pointをあえて出るようにして調べてみたところ
_delegate4486=(id)0x0
と出たので、これが原因かと思い
色々とネットで検索しても解決法が分からず
八方塞がりです。

なぜ上手くいかないのか教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。
色々と試してみたのですが上手くいかなかったので
発想を変えて、ボタンを押すとNSNotificationCenterにメッセージが送られるようにして、MasterViewControllerのほうで受け取ってinsertNewObject:を実行するようにしたらセルに追加されました。
タイトルと異なる解決法で申し訳ありません。

Comment: Unwind segueは初めて知りました。
だいぶ開発がスムーズになりそうです。
情報ありがとうございます^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
// 2行削除
/*
    ViewController* viewC=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    viewC.delegate4486 =self;
}
*/

// 中略

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Segue Identifierは、適宜書きかえてください。
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"Modal") {
        ViewController *controller = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.delegate4486 = self;
    } else {
        // ほかの処理
    }
}

//以下省略
```

Stroyboardで、Segueを使って遷移しているのですから、遷移時（prepareForSegue:）に、遷移先のView Controllerを、Delegateの送り手と設定する（自身をDelegateの受け手とする）のがいいでしょう。

余談：
Storyboardが進歩していて、遷移先に進むことだけでなく、戻る処理もStoryboardで行えるようになっています。戻る処理を「**Unwind Segue**」と呼んでいますが、それをキーワードにするか、「Storyboard Exit」とかをキーワードにして、ネット検索すると、情報を得られるでしょう。すくなくともDelegateを使って、遷移先から戻るより、簡潔なプログラムにすることができます。

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    ViewController* viewC=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    viewC.delegate4486 = self;
}
```

ここのViewControllerを@propertyやインスタンス変数にしてみたらどうでしょうか？

----- 追記 -----
すみません、ざっくりすぎたので少しだけ補足させてください（結局ざっくりですが・・・）

```
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender
```

を実行する**ViewController**と

```
viewC.delegate4486 = self;
```

を設定する**ViewController**を同じインスタンスにしてみてください。